# Style dialog buttons CSS for only 1 jQuery dialog of several on page

Tags: jquery, css, select, button, dialog

I am trying to target the buttons on a jQuery dialog, but only for 1 dialog out of several on the page.

I would normally target the buttons before using:

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane

and

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset

In this case I want to only style the buttons for this one dialog (I want to center them).

The dialog is created from a hidden div:

```
<div id="one" style="display:none;">
  Content of the dialog
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#one").dialog({
    buttons: {"save":function(){alert("saved");}}
  });
});
</script>
```

How can I target just this single dialog with CSS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just CSS you should be able to use the sibling selector, because jQuery UI incorporates the `#one` element into the body of the dialog:

```
#one ~ .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset {
  margin: auto;
  /* whatever other styling you need here */
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was able to use this as follows:  #one ~ .ui-dialog-buttonpane { 
    text-align: center;
}
#one ~ .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset { 
    float: none;
}